# YAXLib crash when serialize Dictionary with null values

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, serialization, yaxlib

I'm using [YAXLib](https://github.com/sinairv/YAXLib) to serialize my objects, I find the following bug in the YAXLib source code:

If I try to serialize a dictionary that contains a null value I got a unhandled `nullReference` exception.

```
Dictionary<string, object> Dict= new Dictionary<string, object>();
Dict.Add("foo", null);
YAXSerializer serializer = new YAXSerializer(typeof (Dictionary<string, object>));
serializer.SerializeToFile(Dict, "path"); // << CRASH
```

Running deep in YAXSerializer.cs I found the following code:

```
foreach (object obj in dicInst) //dicInst is the Dict variable defined above
{
  ...
  // valueObj is null
  XElement addedElem = AddObjectToElement(elemChild, valueAlias, valueObj);
  ...
}

private XElement AddObjectToElement(XElement elem, XName alias, object obj)
{
  //obj is null and so obj.GetType() crash
  UdtWrapper udt = TypeWrappersPool.Pool.GetTypeWrapper(obj.GetType(), this);
  ...
}
```

Some of you faced the same problem?
Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Seems like the mistake would be taken care of if you avoided adding null objects to your dictionary.  Is there a reason you have those values?

Comment: The xml is the representation of the user setting and I'd like to distinguish between empty string setting ("") and no setting at all (null)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the null objects so that they aren't fed into the serializer:

```
var newdata = data.Where(kvp => kvp.Value != null).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Or you can create a new object and set all null values to instances of that object:

```
var newdict = dict.Select(kvp => kvp = new KeyValuePair<string, object>(kvp.Key, kvp.Value == null ? new NullObject() : kvp.Value)).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```